# Useragent not working in react-native-webview

Tags: firebase, react-native, webview, google-signin

Login via google from webview not working

I'm using react-native-webview and trying to login via google from webview

> Error: disallowed_useragent

implemented google sign in from firebase web

```
 <WebView style={styles.WebViewStyle}
      userAgent={DeviceInfo.getUserAgent()}
      automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
      source={{ uri: 'MY_URL' }}
      onLoad={() => this.hideSpinner()} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :-

```
userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"
```